# pattern used in search cmd and option like flp

Tags: vim

according to the vim manual, both the search cmd `/` and the option like `flp` take pattern.

However, I noticed a difference but failed to understand it

- in search cmd, I can type `/a\(b\|c\)` to search for `ab` or `ac`.
- for option set in vimrc like `flp`, all backslashes need another backslash to escape, like `a\\(b\\\|\\)`. For example [this one](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/ftplugin/markdown.vim#L14)

  ```
  setlocal formatlistpat=^\\s*\\d\\+\\.\\s\\+\\\|^[-*+]\\s\\+\\\|^\\[^\\ze[^\\]]\\+\\]:
  ```
- how to understand the difference here, given both refers to use pattern in manuals?
- or when should I use double backslash?

Comment: `:h option-backslash`

Comment: This resolves my confusion. Thanks!